# Search Google Drive for a file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a script to search my Google Drive for a file. The search should only look at the name of the file (not the contents), and look for a string within that name.

For example, there's a file called "2018-08-06_Miller_576132063_17.25.pdf" and I want to have my script search for "576132063" and get the fileID.

If it matters, I would be searching within subfolders of folder: "0B1-kfT4ZOAitb1lZSzM5YXR6czA"

```
function FileFinder() {

  var ShowMeCC = '576132063';
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1-kfT4ZOAitb1lZSzM5YXR6czA').searchFiles('title contains  "' + ShowMeCC + '" ');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fnaMe = file.getName();
    var fID = file.getId();
    Logger.log(fID);
  }

}
```

The search finds nothing.

This seems basic, yet I can't find anyone who asked this specific question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of the API are you using V2 or V3?  Your issue may be that V2 is title V3 its name.

Comment: @DaImTo OP uses Class DriveApp. It seems that Class DriveApp uses Drive API v2 yet. For example, when ``name`` is used as ``q`` like ``DriveApp.searchFiles("name contains 'value'")``, the error related to ``q`` occurs. On the other hand, ``title`` is used, no error occurs. From this situation, I thought that Class DriveApp uses Drive API v2. If I misunderstood your comment, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thats why i am asking getName is v3  if OP is using v2 i would think he should be using getTitle.  Or consider upgrading.

Comment: @DaImTo Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about replying, "getName" is this line of ``var fnaMe = file.getName()``?

Comment: I'm not familiar with V2 or V3... That is, I don't know how I would know this.  I'm not an actual programmer, but someone who tries bits and pieces of things I see on SO.  Thank you for your help on this project everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve files which have the filename including the string of `ShowMeCC`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround?

[The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters#fn1) says as follows.

> The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a title. For example, the title "HelloWorld" would match for title contains 'Hello' but not title contains 'World'.

By this, unfortunately, the file of `2018-08-06_Miller_576132063_17.25.pdf` cannot be directly retrieved using `title contains '576132063'`. So as a workaround, it is considered the following workaround.

- Search the file after all files were retrieved.

In this case, at first, it is required to retrieve all files. But this is the high cost. In order to reduce the cost, I would like to propose 2 step searching.

1. Retrieve files using the query of `fullText contains '576132063'`.

   - `fullText contains '576132063'` can search the filename like `2018-08-06_Miller_576132063_17.25.pdf`.
2. Retrieve the file from files retrieved by `fullText contains '576132063'`.

By this flow, all files are not required to be retrieved. So the cost becomes lower than that of above method.

#### Modified script 1:

```
function FileFinder() {
  var ShowMeCC = '576132063';
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + ShowMeCC + '"'); // Modified
  // OR var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1-kfT4ZOAitb1lZSzM5YXR6czA').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + ShowMeCC + '"'); // Modified
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fnaMe = file.getName();
    if (fnaMe.indexOf(ShowMeCC) > -1) { // Added
      var fID = file.getId();
      Logger.log(fnaMe);
      Logger.log(fID);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters)

If this modification was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

As one more sample, if you want to retrieve the file from a specific folder like `DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1-kfT4ZOAitb1lZSzM5YXR6czA')`, you can also use the following script. When the number of files in the folder is not much, the cost of this method will not become high.

#### Modified script 2:

```
function FileFinderaaa() {
  var ShowMeCC = '576132063';
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1-kfT4ZOAitb1lZSzM5YXR6czA').getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fnaMe = file.getName();
    if (fnaMe.indexOf(ShowMeCC) > -1) {
      var fID = file.getId();
      Logger.log(fnaMe);
      Logger.log(fID);
    }
  }
}
```